# Calling sqlcmd.exe in batch file using variables causes error: "unexpected argument"

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file, cmd, sqlcmd

In a Windows batch file, this works:

```
sqlcmd.exe -b -S xxMySqlServerNamexx -Q "BACKUP DATABASE xxMyDatabaseNamexx TO DISK='d:\data\xxMyDatabaseNamexx.bak' with init, compression"
```

As does this:

```
set vSource_SqlServer="xxMySqlServerNamexx"      
sqlcmd.exe -b -S %vSource_SqlServer% -Q "BACKUP DATABASE xxMyDatabaseNamexx TO DISK='d:\data\xxMyDatabaseNamexx.bak' with init, compression"
```

But this:

```
set vSource_SqlServer="xxMySqlServerNamexx"  
set vSource_SqlDbName="xxMyDatabaseNamexx"  
sqlcmd.exe -b -S %vSource_SqlServer% -Q "BACKUP DATABASE %vSource_SqlDbName% TO DISK='d:\data\xxMyDatabaseNamexx.bak' with init, compression"
```

...causes error:

```
Sqlcmd: 'xxMyDatabaseNamexx" TO DISK='d:\data\xxMyDatabaseNamexx.bak' with init, compression"': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

As you can see it is choking on using a variable `%vSource_SqlDbName%` in place of `xxMyDatabaseNamexx`

Is there a correct way to do this *in this form* (by that I mean, yes I should probably be using Powershell or an alternative approach, but I have several existing batch files in this form that I would prefer to convert to use variables in this form, even if it is not the perfect way to do it)?

Comment: For people trying to use SQL Authentication with sqlcmd and running into similar issue. 

Other things to consider:
1. -U  is not same as –U. The character "-" is the correct one.
2. -u <username> does not work, need to use uppercase "-U".

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set statement does not dequote its arguments.
So `set a=b c` means %a% expands to `b c`, and `set a="b c"` means it expands to `"b c"`.

So in your non-working example you're putting double-quote text inside a double-quoted string, which does not work.

Remove the quoting from the `set`s and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The most secure way to set a variable is to use the syntax (in case [command extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) are enabled, which is the default setting in Windows anyway):

```
set "vSource_SqlDbName=xxMyDatabaseNamexx"
```

Note the quotation marks around the entire expression, so they do not become part of the expanded value. `%vSource_SqlDbName%` is therefore expanded to `vSource_SqlDbName`.